# Nautilus shows files in Trash, can't be located on cli

Tags: directory-structure, nautilus, trash

When browsing to `trash:///` in Nautilus, I see a long list of files and directories that I recognize and remember placing in the trash. However, attempting to delete them from Nautilus either results in a `Preparing` message indefinitely, or an error message `Error while deleting. You do not have sufficient permissions to delete the file "_____".`

I've already emptied `~/.local/share/Trash/files` as my regular user, and that directory does not exist as the `root` user.

I've downloaded the [trash](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/trash/) tool from the AUR to confirm my findings: running `trash -l` or `trash -e` as my regular user and `root` both confirm that the trash can is empty.

I can clearly see that it is not empty though. I'm able to browse through the directories using nautilus and open these files.

**How can I locate these files in order to permanently delete them**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was actually being caused by having a `.Trash-1000` folder on the external drive itself, with all the contents I was seeing in Nautilus within it.

In order to delete these files, I had to remount that drive as writable:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point
```

After this point, I was able to `rm -rf .Trash-1000/` on the drive, and the files were no longer visible as part of the Trash within Nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

In my home directory (using KDE Plasma 5.5.x Konsole) I did

```
micha@linux-micha: ~
$ find | grep -i trash | head
./.local/share/Trash
./.local/share/Trash/info
./.local/share/Trash/files
./.local/share/dolphin/view_properties/trash
./.local/share/dolphin/view_properties/trash/.directory
./.local/share/local-mail/trash
./.local/share/local-mail/trash/cur
./.local/share/local-mail/trash/new
./.local/share/local-mail/trash/tmp
./.config/trashrc
```

So, what's `.config/trashrc` showing in your case Empty=true or Empty=false? Then, what's inside your `.local/share/Trash/info` directory? How much do things match up?

Let me know. -- Regards, Micha